# How to set buttons to be pre-checked in a dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, checkboxlist

I want to ask how to set the state of some items in Dialog check box to be **pre-checked**. I have to following code:

```
String[] typeOfTransport;

    typeOfTransport = new String[modes.length];

    final boolean[] itemsChecked = new boolean[modes.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < modes.length; i++) 
    {       
        typeOfTransport[i] = modes[i].Name;                     
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Select your transport:");
    dialogBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(typeOfTransport, itemsChecked, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener()
    {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) 
        {               
            itemsChecked[which] = isChecked = true;              
        }           
    });

    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Set", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            String selectetdVal = " ";
            for (int i = 0; i < modes[0].Name.length(); i++) 
            {  
               if (itemsChecked[i]) 
               {  
                 selectetdVal = selectetdVal + modes[i].Name+ " ";
                 itemsChecked[i]=false;                  
               }
            }               
            Toast.makeText(MainWindow.this, selectetdVal,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });     

    AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
    return true;
}
```

And I get the dialog correctly everything is set and ready to be checked by the user but I want on some of the items in the dialog to be **pre-checked** when the user calls the dialog for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hat's what the second argument on `setMultiChoiceItems` do, but you are basically passing an array of boolean values recently created (they are all `false`).

Try setting the positions you want **pre-checked** as `true` before calling `setMultiChoiceItems`.

You can reuse the `for` loop you already have to do something like this:

```
final boolean[] itemsChecked = new boolean[modes.length];
for (int i = 0; i < modes.length; i++) 
{       
    typeOfTransport[i] = modes[i].Name;  

    itemsChecked[i] = modes[i].Selected;                 
}
```

Comment: hmm this seems to work party correct for some reason. So basically I have an array "modes" and it contains boolean value. and I make the condition if (modes[i].Selected = true) and it checks every box to be true and all the boxes are checked.

Comment: `if (modes[i].Selected == true)` (you need two equal signs instead of one to compare values). Check my edit and see if it fits your case

Comment: oh right thank :D that stupid mistake I did not saw that my mistake thank you again